# Remove trailing comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace

I have a table with names formatted as "Smith, Stan" and need to display them as "Stan Smith". I was able to do that but it seems that the comma has been left behind and I need to get rid of it.
This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(',', Name) + 1, LEN(Name)) + ' ' +
SUBSTRING(Name, 1, CHARINDEX(',', Name)) AS NewName
FROM Employees
```

[image: what I have vs. what it needs to look like]

Comment: Please show us the original starting data.

Comment: Add `-1` to your query: `.... + SUBSTRING(Name, 1, CHARINDEX(',', Name) - 1) AS NewName`

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546). Providing the DDL and sample input helps us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using replace as below

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(',', Name) + 1, LEN(Name)) + ' ' +
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Name, 1, CHARINDEX(',', Name)),',','') AS NewName
FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all rows contains the comma:

```
SELECT LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(',', Name)-1) + ' ' +
       RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX(',', Name)-1) AS NewName
FROM Employees
```

### Update

If your `Name` column contains trailing spaces, change `LEN` to `DATALENGTH`.  If it's an `nchar` or `nvarchar` column, use `DATALENGTH` but divide by 2:

```
-- if Name is char/varchar
SELECT LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(',', Name)-1) + ' ' +
       RIGHT(Name, DATALENGTH(Name) - CHARINDEX(',', Name)-1) AS NewName
FROM Employees

-- in Name is nchar/nvarchar
SELECT LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(',', Name)-1) + ' ' +
       RIGHT(Name, DATALENGTH(Name)/2 - CHARINDEX(',', Name)-1) AS NewName
FROM Employees
```

Comment: This fails if names have trailing spaces as LEN() ignores them (try a name like 'Smith, Dave  '. @Luuk's comment in the original post will work though.

Comment: Easily fixable with by changing `len` with `datalength` (or `datalength / 2` in case of `nvarchar`)